# Squeak on agressive clutching - Renault Megane

Tags: engine, clutch, renault

I am looking at buying a Renault Megane 2005 1.4 petrol. The car looks in very good condition but it has a subtle squeak if I release the clutch pedal too suddenly ... this is either on gearing up or gearing down ( engine braking ). I gave the clutch itself a good run through the common tests like bite point, stalling the engine in 3rd, etc and it did seem to be fine to me, so I don't think it is that but I could be wrong. It sounded like it could be a squeaky engine mount to me. Has anyone got any options or experience with this.

Comment: Is the squeak a mechanical squeak (metal on metal) or a suspension (dry rubber) kind of squeak?

Comment: Sounds more like rubber but it's fairly faint so I can't be sure it might be metal ... it's very short ( in duration ) each time it occurs ... something similar to brake squeak

Comment: Fortunately from your description, it sounds like more of an annoyance than a real problem. It could be any one of numerous mounts/bushing on the car which are causing this. Finding it would be a real pain. If you like the car and can put up with the squeak, I'd bet it's nothing to worry about. It's not the throw out bearing or the clutch, because the noise would be louder and happen at different times. This leaves the suspension and motor mounts.

Comment: Thanks, that was my own conclusion too ... it's good to get a confirmation. Do you want to turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately from your description, it sounds like more of an annoyance than a real problem. It could be any one of numerous mounts/bushing on the car which are causing this. Finding it would be a real pain. If you like the car and can put up with the squeak, I'd bet it's nothing to worry about. It's not the throw out bearing or the clutch, because the noise would be louder and happen at different times. This leaves the suspension and motor mounts.

Comment: Went back for a second look today (and ended up actually buying the car). I couldn't get it to make the noise at all as it so happens no matter what I did ... something might have settled maybe. Someone said it might have been left idle for a couple of weeks before the first test drive and that might have been why something was squeaking ... didn't end up determining it to be serious either way.

Comment: @byronyasgur ... Enjoy your new (to you) car. The "Someone" you mention advice seems spot on. Hopefully it does not return, but if it does, I'm sure it will not be too much to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Your Megane can have a four speed or a five speed box. This means the clutch can be cable operated or hydraulic operated. On a cable clutch you can have squeaks from the clutch pedal bushing, the cable attachment at the pedal, and also from the cable itself. The cable wears internally on bends in the cable. The inner cable cuts through its neoprene inner tubing and rubs on the outer cable. The hydraulic system has inside the car the same type of bushing and attachment and can squeak. In addition, the push rod on the slave cylinder on the gearbox is metal and pushes against the release lever, which is also metal. These too can squeak when dry.

Comment: thanks ... note this doesn't happen on normal clutching just when I release it with a good bit of throttle